# What's the Purpose of pin 44 on IDE cables

Tags: cables, pinout, ide, drive, hdd

So I was looking at the pinout for 44 pin, notebook type IDE cables, and the 44th pin is listed as /TYPE : Type (0=ATA), what use does it have?

[image: pinout]

Comment: please add a link to the source of the diagram to your question ... use the `edit` button ... do not write a comment

Answer (score 0):

It has no use.

ATA-6 standard says the pin is "Reserved - no connection".

So does ATA-4.

ATA-3 standard says the pin is "TYPE- 0=ATA", but does not explain or define it.

Most likely just an error that it was thought to be used for some kind of type indication but feature and description was removed and the table was not updated before releasing the ATA-3 standard.